# Difference between scipy.optimize.fmin and scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm learning python to make models these days. I read the documentation of `scipy.optimize.fmin`. It also recommends `scipy.optimize.minimize`. It seems that `scipy.optimize.minimize` is a more advanced method. Real wonder what's the difference between these two.

Answer (score 6):

[`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) is a high-level interface that lets you choose from a broad range of solvers, one of which is Nelder–Mead. [`scipy.optimize.fmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html) is a special solver using Nelder–Mead. For a specific subdocumentation of `minimize` with Nelder–Mead, see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-neldermead.html#optimize-minimize-neldermead).

Comment: if i understand correctly, then `scipy.optimize.minimize` is more general vs `scipy.optimize.fmin` is more specific. And by extension you can do exactly what `fmin` does with `minimize` by choosing the Nelder-Mead method.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith at a first glance I'd say yes. Comparing [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-neldermead.html#optimize-minimize-neldermead) and [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html) and references therein might suggest that there are differences between the implementations. For instance the latter doesn't have an `adaptive` keyword argument. Depending on how hands-on you want your minimization to be they might differ.

Comment: ya i noticed the missing "adaptive" (i.e. dynamic) parameter in the `fmin` as the main difference. (short aside/non-sequitar: i read a little about that specific feature. for high-dimensional problems the traditional code is unusually slow and so this parameter can significantly speed up the optimizer)